# load-* hook for dashboard

Tags: hooks, dashboard

I'm trying to add a screen option to the dashboard screen.

I have a function like:

```
my_function() {

    ...
    add_screen_option()
    ...

}
```

Now, I need to know the correct action hook $hook to use hooking in my function when the dashboard screen is loaded:

```
add_action( "load-$hook", 'my_function' );
```

What should $hook be?

Comment: Depends on the page you want to address. Show the code for that.

Comment: that would be the main dashboard screen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
add_action( 'load-index.php', 'the_function', 1, 0 );
```

The `load-{page_hook}` hook works with the filename of the page to load.